# Can you rebind the 'next menu element' key in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I use eclipse and when I do code completion, I'd really like to keep my hands on the home row and push "CTRL-N" for the next code completion suggestion, and "CTRL-P" for the previous one. I'm not seeing anything that looks like what I need in the Preferences > General > Keys menu. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Basically, you don't want to have to use the up/down arrows to scroll through the list?

Comment: So I tried the Emacs bindings in the Keys section and it in fact had what I wanted - so I figured out from that that the bindings I wanted were "Line Up" and "Line Down". I'd answer my own question but my puny reputation won't let me for another 8 hours.

Comment: Great! You definitely should add (and accept) your own answer when the site will let you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment above:

> I figured out from that that the bindings I wanted were "Line Up" and "Line Down".